# in terms of being / having been + past tense

Tags: grammar, tenses

Good day to everybody.

Let's say we describe a tennis match that happened a couple of weeks ago.

> Despite a bad start for Federer in the fifth set, in terms of **being** one break down, he won the set and the match.
>
> Despite a bad start for Federer in the fifth set, in terms of **having been** one break down, he won the set and the match.

Although it seems to me that the second statement is correct, the first one sound more natural, but I do not know if it is correct.

Are both ok to use?

Not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine.

> Despite a bad start for Federer in the fifth set, in terms of being one break down, he won the set and the match.

Should be read as:

> Despite a bad start for Federer in the fifth set, in terms of being one break down *(at one point)*, he won the set and the match.

Comment: "in terms of" seems like a strange phrase to use there, don't you think? Wouldn't "in spite of" be more appropriate?

Comment: @Barmar, why? being a break down is actually a bad thing

Comment: @Davo, that is a nice observation, indeed the "at one/some point" is implicit

Comment: @hamster That's my point. "in spite of" means that the outcome was unlikely because of the stated condition. "in terms of" means with regard to a particular feature of something.

Comment: @Barmar ah, I understand now. In my case I use the "in terms of..." as an explanation to why Federer had a bad start, so it was a bad start in the sense that he was down a break. In your case I think you use "in spite of..." as an additional bad thing like "Despite a bad start, and in spite of a bad follow-up, he succeeded in the end."

Comment: Oh, of course -- I didn't notice that the quote already had "despite" in it. You're right that this is a clarification of what the bad start was.